# Facing Error During Tibco AMX Deployment : "AMX Invalid boolean value 'False'"

Tags: soa, tibco

When Deploying an Application I am facing issues. After looking at the node logs I found this Error:

```
"org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlValueOutOfRangeException: Invalid boolean value 'False'
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When looking into the substitution Variables in Tibco admin and Property file I realize there were two Boolean SV defined. I had to remove it from our script and deploy the application. The application deployed just fine. Later on I went into admin and changed the default Boolean values to desired values.
Alternatively, Try SV Boolean values in the lower letters.

Comment: Note, in AMX  Deployment script Boolean must be in small alphabets example false, true